# Show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_k^{\infty} f(x)dx =0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a non negative integrable function over $\mathbb{R}$, show that:

$$\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \int_k^{\infty} f(x)dx = 0$$

---

I was trying it in the following way:

Since $f$ is integrable it is bounded so for each $j>k$ let $M_{j} = \sup_{x \in (k,j)} f(x)$, then:

$$ \int_k^j f(x) dx \leq M_{j} (j-k)$$

So if $k \to j$ then $\int_k^j f(x) dx \to 0$

That question has been asked in: [How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^\infty f(x) dx = 0$ when $f$ is integrable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958240/how-to-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-int-n-infty-fx-dx-0-when-f-is-integ) but that question was asked in a context of the Lebesgue integral. My question is for the Riemann integral using calculus concepts.

Comment: You have improper integrals $\int_k^\infty f(x)dx$, which is defined as $\int_k^\infty f(x)dx=\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_k^t f(x)dx$, correct?

Comment: Integrable functions are not necessarily bounded. (Also a proof about the situation $k\to j$ doesn't say anything about the original integral.)

Answer (score 2):

Since $\int_k^\infty f(x)dx\geqslant 0$, either $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_k^\infty f(x)dx=0$ or there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, we can find $k>t$ such that $\int_k^\infty f(x)dx>\epsilon$.

The definition of the improper integral $\int_k^\infty f(x)dx=\lim_{l\to\infty}\int_k^l f(x)dx$. So if $\int_k^\infty f(x)dx>\epsilon$, there exists $l>k$ such that $\int_k^l f(x)dx>\epsilon$.

Combining these first two paragraphs yields that if $\int_k^\infty f(x)dx$ does not tend to $0$ as $k\to\infty$, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, there exist $t<k<l$ such that $\int_k^l f(x)dx>\epsilon$. Let $l_0=0$ and recursively select $l_0<k_1<l_1<k_2<l_2<\ldots$ such that $\int_{k_n}^{l_n} f(x)dx>\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $$\infty>\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx \geqslant \int_{-\infty}^{l_n}f(x)dx \geqslant \sum_{m=1}^n \int_{k_n}^{l_n} f(x)dx >n\epsilon.$$ This is a contradiction for $n>\epsilon^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$.